# Pip install does not find package, but pip search does

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to install the [hdbcli](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/) package (SAP HANA connector).

When I search with `pip` the package is being found, but when I want to install it, `pip` can't find the package.

Specifiying the current package also yields no results.

```
pip install hdbcli==2.6.61
```

How do I solve this?

```bash
> pip search hbdcli
hdbcli (2.6.61) - SAP HANA Python Client

> pip install hdbcli
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hdbcli (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for hdbcli
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This usually means *pip* could not find any *distribution* of that project that would be compatible with your python environment:

- Python implementation (CPython, or PyPy, etc.)
- Python interpreter *major* and *minor* version (3.10, or 3.11, etc.)
- operating system (Windows, or Linux, etc.)
- CPU bitness (64 bits or 32 bits)

This project does not seem to have published any *source distribution* (*sdist*) ever. So it has to be a compatible wheel.

Are you by chance on Python 3.9? As far as I can tell there are no *wheel* distributions for Python 3.9.

Use `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip debug --verbose` to get a list of "*Compatible tags*". Then compare this list with the [list of available *wheel* distributions for that project](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/2.6.61/#files).

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I looked into it and I think the problem is that the package needs a 64bit Python installation, while I have a 32bit installed. It doesn't specify it in the package's README, but I found a hint about it on another website...  I will reinstall and try it again.

Comment: I installed Python 3.8 (64 bit). It's a bit weird that they don't specify it in the package's readme file, but it works now. (additionally you were right, it does not work with a 3.9  64bit version)

Comment: It is somewhat indicated in the so-called _trove classifiers_. See the "Programming languages" section towards the bottom of the left sidebar on the [project's page](https://pypi.org/project/hdbcli/).

Comment: The Python 3.x versions yes, but not he bit-version of Python itself.

Answer (score -1):

Try [manual install](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/latest/en-US/39eca89d94ca464ca52385ad50fc7dea.html).
Maybe the library isnt sync