# Pip is unable to find version for package in Linux server

Tags: python, pip

I am attempting to host a Django app through a Linux server. Problem I am running into is when I do `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get the following error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement click==8.1.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.7, 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7.dev0, 6.7, 7.0, 7.1, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0a1, 8.0.0rc1, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4) ERROR: No matching distribution found for click==8.1.3` I get this error for a few different packages I am trying to install.

I know click version 8.1.3 exists and its the one I’m using when I tested locally. Why is pip unable to find it?

local os: windows 10 64-bit
server: Oracle Linux Server release 8.6

Comment: Have you updated to the latest `pip` with `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip`?

Comment: @AaronMeese yes. Still no luck.

Comment: Try checking out this thread and seeing if it makes sense for your question, my guess is that Oracle *may* be the cause of this particular issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034961/6456163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last version in the error message, [click 8.0.4](https://pypi.org/project/click/8.0.4/) requires Python >= 3.6. Version [8.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/click/8.1.3/) requires Python >= 3.7. From this I can deduce you're using Python 3.6. Either use click 8.0.4, the last version that supports Python 3.6. Or upgrade to later Python version, at least 3.7.

Comment: This solved it. I upgraded to python 3.9 and all the packages installed. Thank you